# Mobile menu stacking context

Tags: mobile, overflow, css-position, z-index

My mobile menu tray is appearing behind my content-

http://kmgp.preview.learningpool.com/
(in tablet view)

The menu tray is appearing at the top and the bottom of the page

The website is an e-learning site on moodle 2.5.

Below is the code from the page and menu tray:

```
.mobile #page {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mobile #page-header .meta {
    background: #F7F7F7;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: visible !important;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 200;
}

.mobile #page-header .banner {
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

i had hoped that reducing the `z-index` on the menu tray and adding a higher `z-index` to the banner would allow the banner to sit tight to the top of the page and hide the content you can see when scrolling.

This is the menu when open, when a user scrolls to go down the page, the menu will appear for about 60px at the top and bottom of the page:

[image]